# Solve Equation trinomial Nine degree!

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to solve equation:  `x^9+p*x^4−q==0`, {p, q} ∈C using functional analysis. Ηow do I solve this equation and with help Mathematica program for case  p=π, q=e)?
[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful to have cut-and-pastable Mathematica InputForm. I believe this point has been made a few times now.

Comment: Relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202201/9469

Comment: See also here https://mathoverflow.net/a/249098/41145

Comment: Since  Mathematica v12.3 (experimental feature)) and now v13.0 the new FoxH function  can solve trinomial equations explicitly

Answer (score 2):

```
f[p_, q_, x_] = x^9 + p*x^4 - q;

sol = x /. Solve[f[Pi, E, x] == 0, x]

(* {Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 1], Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 2], 
 Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 3], Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 4], 
 Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 5], Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 6], 
 Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 7], Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 8], 
 Root[-E + π #1^4 + #1^9 &, 9]} *)
```

The solutions are given in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. The numerical values can be obtained using [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

```
sol // N[#, 20] & // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce[x^9 + π*x^4 - e == 0, x] // N ,,,,,,,,=>                                                                         
 x == 0.919688 || x == -1.08673 - 0.106027 I || 
 x == -1.08673 + 0.106027 I || x == -0.469834 - 1.17648 I || 
 x == -0.469834 + 1.17648 I || x == 0.050413 - 0.943033 I || 
 x == 0.050413 + 0.943033 I || x == 1.04631 - 0.798312 I || 
 x == 1.04631 + 0.798312 I

Comment: In your comment, `e` **must** be written as `E`. Built-in symbols all start with capital letters.

Comment: The data π,e gives from Palettes of program mathematica 10 and Up

Comment: The `e` is in a different script. Copy and paste the code from your comment into a workbook and it will not give the desired results.

Comment: it is not necessary in E format...I Will say again from Palettes..