# Simple Solve[{y == 5 + 2 x + x^a}, {x}] not working?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find a general expression for `x`, for the following equation `y = 5 + 2 x + x^a`, but Solve cannot accomplish this.

I am using `Solve[{y == 5 + 2 x + x^a}, {x}]`

If I put any numerical for `a`, for example `a = 0.5`, it works and it gives me the roots, but it doesn't give me a general expression for any `a`.

`a` is between `0` and `1`, i.e `0 < a < 1`.

How can I get a general expression for `x` as a function of `y` and `a`?

Comment: For general `a` mathematically is **impossible** to obtain a symbolic(analytic) solution,
because there is a lack of **tools** in mathematics to solve this equation.Then **Mathematica** can't solve.

Comment: A symbolic solution is only possible for a rational $a$, it is then expressible in terms of the hypergeometric function. For an irrational $a$, a solution is only possible in terms of series. See here, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation

Comment: The irrational $a$ case @yarchik was talking about is expressible as a Fox $H$-function, which degenerates to a sum of Meijer $G$-functions (equivalently, a sum of hypergeometric functions) when $a$ is rational. Unfortunately Fox $H$ is not yet implemented in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 10):

## Generic trinomial equation $w x^a-x+1=0$

A particular solution such that $x→1$ for $w→0$ is known in analytical form [M.L.Glasser, J. Comp. Appl. Math. **118**, 169 (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00287-9)

```
f[a_,w_]:=1+Sum[w^n/n Binomial[a n,n-1],{n,1,∞}]
```

#### Example A.1 *simple quadratic equation*

```
α=2;
x=f[α,w]
Simplify[1-x+ w x^α]
Out[1]= 1+(1-Sqrt[1-4 w]-2 w)/(2 w)
Out[2]= 0
```

#### Example A.2 *cubic equation*

```
α=3;
x=f[α,w]
Simplify[1-x+ w x^α]
Out[3]= 1+(-3 Sqrt[w]+2 Sqrt[3] Sin[1/3 ArcSin[(3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[w])/2]])/(3 Sqrt[w])
Out[4]= 0
```

---

## Trinomial equation of the type $x^α-p x+q=0$

Solution is obtained from a generic formula by simple rescaling

```
g[a_,p_,q_]:=(q/p) f[a,q^(a-1)/p^a]
```

#### Example B.1 *general quadratic equation*

```
Clear[α,p,q]
p=-2;
α=2;
x=g[α,p,q]
Simplify[x^α-p x+q]
Out[5]= -(1/2) (1+(2-2 Sqrt[1-q]-q)/q) q
Out[6]= 0
```

#### Example B.2 *cubic equation*

```
Clear[α,p,q]
p=-2;
α=3;
x=g[α,p,q]
Simplify[x^α-p x+q]
Out[7]= -(1/2) q (1+(-3 q+4 Sqrt[6] Sinh[1/3 ArcSinh[3/4 Sqrt[3/2] q]])/(3 q))
Out[8]= 0
```

#### Example B.3 *quintic*

```
Clear[α,p,q]
p=-2;
α=5;
x=g[α,p,q]
Series[x^α-p x+q,{q,0,10}]//Normal
Out[9]= -(1/2) q HypergeometricPFQ[{1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5},{1/2,3/4,5/4},-((3125 q^4)/8192)]
Out[10]= 0
```

#### Example B.4 *exponent $\frac52$*

```
Clear[α,p,q]
p=-2;
α=5/2;
x=g[α,p,q]
N[x^α-p x+q/.q->-1]
Out[11]= -(1/2) q (1+1/8 (-8+8 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5},{1/2,2/3,4/3},-((3125 q^3)/3456)]
                          -I Sqrt[2] q^(3/2) HypergeometricPFQ[{7/10,9/10,11/10,13/10},{7/6,3/2,11/6},-((3125 q^3)/3456)]))
Out[12]= 8.32667*10^-17
```

---

Trinomial equations is an interesting piece of mathematics. The case of integer exponents is discussed in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-can-i-get-the-solutions-of-xn-x-t-0-in-hypergeometric-form) here, the case of arbitrary real exponents is discussed in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation) on mathoverflow. They can be summarized as follows:

1. Chip Hurst obtains solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions by expanding in series the `Root` object.
2. J.M. arrives at another form in terms of `MeijerG` functions by generalizing the method in the Glasser's paper.
3. Pietro Majer derives a series solution by using the inversion formula  for the function $f(x)=x+ax^p+bx^q$ with real exponents $p>1$ and $q>1$.

Comment: It seems I've seen this equation, or a similar one, on this site in years past.  It would be nice to link it, if someone can find it, especially if it's equivalent. (I failed.) +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you, the post is expanded now to show the connections.