# is the Fox-Wright Psi solution of the trinomial equation implemented in mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

According to (13.4)  in Belkic: the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from
the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function
https://d-nb.info/1176090631/34

the solution of

```
Solve[x == 1 + t x^n, x]
```

is called confluent Fox-Wright function with four parameters(a particular case of Fox-H function).  Solve is unaware of this.  Is this special function implemented at all, under some name? The closest I came up with is  Hypergeometric1F1, but that has only two parameters

Comment: There have already been similar posts and answers here, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202201/9469

Comment: Also, The case of integer exponents is discussed in this post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-can-i-get-the-solutions-of-xn-x-t-0-in-hypergeometric-form), the case of arbitrary real exponents is discussed in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation) on mathoverflow.